# In J2me lWUIT Library how to arrange long text on Label?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am using LWUIT Library. I want to add same long information of project on `AboutUS FORM`. I'm using label but information become lost. If I am not using `TextArea` then what is another Solution?

My Another Question is,

In `Login Form`, what should be used `TextField` or `TextArea`?

Answer (score 1):

`Label` is not good for showing long information. because its not allow to show multiple lines. Better you can use with `TextArea` and set the editable mode to false. If you dont want to use `TextArea` means just start the ticker on the `Label`.

Use `TextField` for login page.

Comment: I would also add that to make the TextArea look like a label use textArea.setUIID("Label")